# AJAX/JQUERY - Split the returned data and place in two seperate divs

Tags: ajax, jquery, split

I am currently using the following code to run an AJAX query every 10 seconds to populate `<div id="datacontainer"></div>`

```
setInterval(function(){
$.ajax({
    url: "ajax.php",
    type: "GET", 
    cache: false}
).done(function(html) {
$( '#datacontainer' ).html( html );});},10000
);
```

I have now setup the ajax.php file to return a string that now contains the delimiter '----' that I want to split and populate two div's.

I want to split into `data[]` when split `data[0]` goes into `<div id="nummessages"></div>` and `data[1]` goes to `<div id="datacontainer"></div>`

How would this code need to be modified to achieve this?

Answer (score 12, accepted):

```
setInterval(function(){
  $.ajax({
      url: "ajax.php",
      type: "GET", 
      cache: false}
  ).done(function(html) {
    var divs = html.split('----');
    $( '#nummessages' ).html( divs[0] );
    $( '#datacontainer' ).html( divs[1] );
  });
},10000);
```

Comment: Thank you!!! That has been racking my brain for a few hours now!. I will tick your answer in a few minutes, it won't let me right now.

Comment: Occam's Razor, this works and is easy to implement. +