# interlinked dropdown list is not working

Tags: php, jquery, ajax

i am working with interlinked dropdown list i.e on selection of one dropdown list ajax call generated and populated another dropdown list and so on.

So my problem is with data coming from server side,on selection of each dropdown list i want to filter the available-results also,but the data that coming from server side get appended to `show div` i.e `dropdown-list items and results-items`.i only want to append `results-items to show div`.
**client side code**

```
        var country_code = $(this).val();
    console.log(country_code);
    if(country_code){
         $('#loadingmessage').show(); 
        $.ajax({
            type:'POST',
            url:'dependent.php',
            data:'country_code='+country_code,
            success:function(html){
                console.log(html);
                $('#state').html(html);
                $('#city').html('<option value="">Select state first</option>'); 
                $('#results').html(html);
                $('#loadingmessage').hide();
            }
        }); 
    }else{
        $('#state').html('<option value="">Select country first</option>');
        $('#city').html('<option value="">Select state first</option>'); 
    }
});
```

**server side code**

```
 if(isset($_POST["country_code"]) && !empty($_POST["country_code"])){
    $id = 1;
$code = $_POST['country_code'];
$code = mysqli_real_escape_string($conn,$code);
$query = "SELECT * FROM plus2_state WHERE country_code = '$code' ORDER BY state ASC";
$result = mysqli_query($conn,$query) or die(mysqli_error($conn));
$rowCount = mysqli_num_rows($result);
if($rowCount > 0){
    while($row = mysqli_fetch_array($result)){ 
        echo '<option class="state_option" value="'.$row['state_id'].'">'.$row['state'].'</option>';        
    }
}else{
    echo '<option class="state_option" value="">State not available</option>';
}
$query_1 = "SELECT * from content where country_code = '$code' ORDER BY emp_name ASC";
$result_1 = mysqli_query($conn,$query_1) or die(mysqli_error($conn));
$row_count = mysqli_num_rows($result_1);
$_SESSION['result'] = array();
if($row_count > 0 )
{
    while($content_rows = mysqli_fetch_array($result_1))
    {
        unset($_SESSION['result']);
        echo "<div class='result'><div class='col-md-3 photo-grid' style = 'float:left'>
            <div class = 'well well-sm'><h4><small>".$content_rows['emp_name']."</small></h4></div></div></div>";
            $_SESSION['result'][$id] =  array('name' => $content_rows['emp_name']);
    }
}
else
{
    echo "<div class = 'result'>no results found</div>";
}
$_SESSION['country_code'] = $code ;
//print_r($_SESSION['result']);
}
```

Comment: Don't know whether I have understood the question properly or not.  Whatever you echo in server side code will be available in 'html' of the ajax function.  So whichever you don't want, don't echo in server side code.

Comment: interlinked mean `chained select boxes`,everything is working fine,but if you see closely in server side code i'm echoing two statements with different classes ,which i have to append to different div's on front end, main problem is i am unable to extract the ajax data to place it in different div's

Comment: try something like this - http://stackoverflow.com/questions/21298271/ajax-jquery-split-the-returned-data-and-place-in-two-seperate-divs.   In your case echo "----" once one div is done.